# Is this lazy initialization pattern for objects in a hashmap thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, hashmap

I want to avoid locking on read if possible.  But this "feels" like double-checked locking, even though no partially initialized members are involved.

Is this a good construct?

```
private final Map<String, Stuff> stash = new HashMap<String, Stuff>();

public Stuff getStuff(String name) {

    if (stash.containsKey(name))
        return stash.get(name);

    synchronized(stash) {
        if (stash.containsKey(name)) {
            return stash.get(name);
        }
        else {
            Stuff stuff = StuffFactory.create(name);
            stash.put(name, stuff);
            return stuff;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use something like Guava's [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) unless this is for fun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this construct is not thread-safe.

Assume that thread `writer` is putting something into the map, and the map, being too small, must be resized. This is done inside the `synchronized` block, so you may think you are fine.

During the resizing, nothing in the map is guaranteed.

Now, at the very same time, assume that a thread `reader` calls `getStuff` for an existing element. This thread may access the map directly, since it doesn't hit the `synchronized` block for the first call to `containsKey` and `get`. It will find the map at an undefined state, and although it only reads, it accesses data whose contents is undefined. Among probable results are:

- `getStuff` returns `null` when it shouldn't.
- `getStuff` returns the intended `Stuff`.
- `getStuff` returns some internal object that is used by the `HashMap` implementation during resizing.
- `getStuff` returns some other `Stuff`, unrelated to the name.
- `getStuff` gets caught in an infinite loop.

This is just the obvious case that should be easy to understand. So no, don't take shortcuts when there are well-designed classes like [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) or Guava's [`MapMaker`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html).

By the way: Calling `containsKey` first and then `get` with the same key is rather inefficient. Just call `get`, save the result and compare it to `null`. You will save one searching operation in the map.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `HashMap` with `ConcurrentHashMap`, your impl is fine.

A more general solutions has to worry about following things

1 . name based locking, not global locking. if `create(n1)` blocks, it shouldn't affect operations on other names.

2 . what if `create()` returns null or throws exception. interestingly this is a problem for some impl.

3 . what if `create(n1)` calls `get(n1)`? we'll have a recursion. some impl hangs. some impl detects recursion and throws error. a better impl should allow recursion to run (which either terminates or stack overflow), and intermediate result should be visible to the locking thread, but invisible to other threads, until the recursion is terminated.